# DNS Resolution Inconsistency

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I'm getting differing address information from the same server when using nslookup on two separate machines on our network (though on separate VLANs).  The steps I take (in a Windows command prompt) to duplicate the problem are:

```
nslookup
> server.yyy.com
> machine.aaa.bbb.com
```

On test computer #1 (test1.aaa.bbb.com), I see the following output

```
Server: server.yyy.com
Addresses:  192.168.2.1
          192.168.1.1

Name:    machine.aaa.bbb.com
Address:  192.168.40.40
```

On test computer #2 (test2.aaa.bbb.com), I see the following output

```
Server: server.yyy.com
Addresses:  192.168.1.1
          192.168.2.1

Name:    machine.aaa.bbb.com
Address:  192.168.200.24
```

The things to notice are:

A) The same server (server.yyy.com) is returning different IP addresses for a specific computer (machine.aaa.bbb.com).  In one case, it's 192.168.40.40 and in the other, it's 192.168.200.24.

B) The 'Addresses' for server.yyy.com are in opposite order depending on which test computer nslookup is performed on.

My question is - how do I get server.yyy.com to respond with the same (and hopefully correct) IP address regardless of which interface is being used?

P.S.  Apologies in advance for any style/terminology errors, or missing information - I'm a noob on this forum, but am glad to provide any further information.

Comment: Are you sure 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1 are the same server?  If so, the configuration may be differentiating responses based on the client's source IP address.  You also didn't indicate the DNS server's OS/code-base.  If it's Unix-based and running BIND, this "smells" like ` sortlist {}; `

Comment: Interesting question - I can't really say for sure if it's actually the same server.  Since I'm specifying the DNS server to use (as I believe is indicated in the nslookup output since both outputs specify the server to be the same), I would have thought it would be the same server.  As for the OS/code-base, I can't really say - this is part of our IT organization "magic" and I'm not sure who I could ask that would know (I haven't had much luck with the first-level IT support and it's next to impossible to get to the next level).